# Como criar/utilizar o schema builder?

Tags: java

Estou tentando criar um schema builder, porém eu não sei diretamente como se faz um, olhando o [Manual](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/api/java/org/apache/avro/SchemaBuilder.html) me deparo com o seguinte código, porém tento implementar no meu código Java e não consigo criar.

No caso irei mostrar o JSON que está no [manual](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/api/java/org/apache/avro/SchemaBuilder.html) e sua implementação Java. Percebi também que tem uma aspas abrindo mas não fechando, tentei fechar ela mas não resolveu o problema, não sei exatamente se é assim mesmo o código ou erraram no manual.

Exemplo do JSON:

```
 {
 "type": "record",
 "name": "HandshakeRequest", "namespace":"org.apache.avro.ipc",
 "fields": [
 {"name": "clientHash",
  "type": {"type": "fixed", "name": "MD5", "size": 16}},
 {"name": "clientProtocol", "type": ["null", "string"]},
 {"name": "serverHash", "type": "MD5"},
 {"name": "meta", "type": ["null", {"type": "map", "values": "bytes"}]}
 ]
}
```

Exemplo do código Java:

```
   Schema schema = SchemaBuilder
  .record("HandshakeRequest").namespace("org.apache.avro.ipc)
  .fields()
  .name("clientHash").type().fixed("MD5").size(16).noDefault()
  .name("clientProtocol").type().nullable().stringType().noDefault()
  .name("serverHash").type("MD5")
  .name("meta").type().nullable().map().values().bytesType().noDefault()
  .endRecord();
```

Bibliotecas utilizadas:

```
import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.SchemaBuilder;
```

Queria saber se a implementação do código está correta, caso não gostaria de um exemplo de como ficaria para implementar o código acima.

O erro que está dando é erro de sintaxe e não de compilação, se isto for ajudar em algo. Só gostaria que me ajudasse a acertar a sintaxe e explicasse um pouco melhor sobre como funciona o schema builder e o erro acontece na linha 2 do código Java:

> "Illegal line end in string literal"

Que acredito que seja pela falta do fechamento da aspas no código do Manual:

```
.record("HandshakeRequest").namespace("org.apache.avro.ipc)
```

Porém mesmo fechando as aspas ocorre um erro nesta linha:

```
.name("meta").type().nullable().map().values().bytesType().noDefault()
```

O erro:

> Cannot Resolve method 'name.(java.lang.String)'

Acredito que o código do manual esteja errado, por isto acredito que seja importante mostrar como utilizar o builder para o Schemabuilder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>*Não tenho o costume de usar esses schemas de JSON, mas vamos lá...*</sup>

---

De fato, o código da documentação está errado, pois nem sequer compila.

O erro *"Illegal line end in string literal"* você já matou, faltou fechar as aspas no trecho `namespace("org.apache.avro.ipc)`.

Quanto ao erro *"Cannot Resolve method 'name.(java.lang.String)'"*, o problema está nesta linha:

```
.name("serverHash").type("MD5")
```

O método [`type()`](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/api/java/org/apache/avro/SchemaBuilder.FieldBuilder.html#type(java.lang.String)) retorna um [`org.apache.avro.SchemaBuilder.GenericDefault`](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/api/java/org/apache/avro/SchemaBuilder.GenericDefault.html), que é uma classe que não possui nenhum método chamado `name`. Daí o erro "*Cannot Resolve method name*", pois o método `name` não existe nesta classe.

Na verdade esta classe, [segundo a documentação](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/api/java/org/apache/avro/SchemaBuilder.GenericDefault.html), só possui os métodos `noDefault()` (indicando que o campo não terá um valor *default*), e `withDefault(Object valor)` (indicando qual será o valor *default* do campo).

Então faltou chamar um destes métodos, pois eles retornam um [`org.apache.avro.SchemaBuilder.FieldAssembler`](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/api/java/org/apache/avro/SchemaBuilder.FieldAssembler.html) (esta sim, uma classe que possui o [método `name()`](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/api/java/org/apache/avro/SchemaBuilder.FieldAssembler.html#name(java.lang.String))). Ex:

```
Schema schema = SchemaBuilder
  .record("HandshakeRequest").namespace("org.apache.avro.ipc") // <-- fecha as aspas
  .fields()
    .name("clientHash").type().fixed("MD5").size(16).noDefault()
    .name("clientProtocol").type().nullable().stringType().noDefault()
    .name("serverHash").type("MD5").noDefault() // <-- Faltou chamar noDefault() (ou withDefault(valorDefault))
    .name("meta").type().nullable().map().values().bytesType().noDefault()
  .endRecord();
System.out.println(schema.toString(true));
```

Este código imprime:

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "HandshakeRequest",
  "namespace" : "org.apache.avro.ipc",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "clientHash",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "fixed",
      "name" : "MD5",
      "size" : 16
    }
  }, {
    "name" : "clientProtocol",
    "type" : [ "string", "null" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "serverHash",
    "type" : "MD5"
  }, {
    "name" : "meta",
    "type" : [ {
      "type" : "map",
      "values" : "bytes"
    }, "null" ]
  } ]
}
```